# Confusion about heap, stack and memory in general in C

Tags: c, memory

I'm new to memory management and have just begun to look into it. From what I know:

- Stack-This is the section of memory that stores all the variables and other temporary data. I'm more confident about this and there isn't much confusion here.
- Heap-From what I know, it is the portion of memory that is not static and can has its size changed and can be allocated during the runtime of the program. It requires manually allocating memory.

I have looked at quite a few sources on this topic but am unsure about the heap mainly. Some sources say that data stored in the heap stays there after the program ends until you call free(). Other sources say that both heap and stack are cleared once the program end. If this is true, where is data stored after runtime? Also why do I need to free() my data if malloc() creates data on the heap which is automatically cleared at the end of the program.

Any other information and recommendations on memory basics are appreciated.

Comment: "other non-temporary data"? The stack very much is temporary in a sense, as its contents change constantly when functions are being entered and exited.

Comment: Data in memory is stored nowhere, unless you do so explicitly in your program. This includes storing in files or databases or sending it via an API to an external service.

Comment: https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs225/fa2022/resources/stack-heap/ looks decent.

Comment: All this stuff is implementation dependent. But typically the stack doesn't store **all variables**. Variables with static storage duration (e.g. global variables) are typically not stored on the stack.

Comment: And typically **all memory is released** when a program terminates.

Comment: One reason to call `free` is to make the memory available for a later `malloc`. In other words - a specific chunk of memory may be used for different things during the life time of a program where you do `malloc`, `free`, `malloc`, `free`, `malloc`, `free`, etc.

Comment: So from what I've learnt: All memory is released when program terminates regardless of where it is stored. To store it you must have a separate storage system e.g. database files etc. and calling free() is good practice for other malloc(). Does this mean it is not necessary to call free() if you will only be using on malloc() since system will free it for you anyways?

Comment: @AerospaceMilitary420 _"Does this mean it is not necessary to call free() if you will only be using on malloc() since system will free it for you anyways?"_ - Sort of - but if you have a long running program that only does `malloc` and never `free`s, then eventually, `malloc` will fail. Also: If you want to analyze such a problem years after the program was written, it can get hard to find unwanted memory leaks if your program has "deliberate" memory leaks.

Comment: It's a common misconception that there's just a stack and a heap. I once wrote a post trying to clear this misconception here: [What gets allocated on the stack and the heap?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277536)

Comment: @AerospaceMilitary420 Calling free() is still good practice, because when you do so you'll spot any bugs related to pointers pointing at the wrong location early on. When free() crashes, you have found such a bug and it is almost always located somewhere else in the program and not on the line that called free().

Comment: @AerospaceMilitary420, The concepts of _stack_ and _heap_ are not needed to understand C.  IMO, instead study _lifetime_ , _scope_ and _allocated memory_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack memory is where automatic data is stored on most systems: data defined locally in function bodies that is not explicitly qualified as `static`.

Heap memory is where `malloc()` and friends get blocks of data from.  It is allocated to the program by the operating system and is usually automatically deallocated when the program ends. There are special cases where the heap memory is not freed when the program ends, if there is no operating system, but these cases are very rare.

Blocks allocated from the heap cannot always be reallocated to a different size, and such reallocation may involve moving the data to a different address, which is confusing and error prone, so changing the size of an allocated object is somewhat of a misnomer.

There is no hard requirement to `free()` the objects allocated from the heap, but it is considered good style, and in some cases it is very important:

- if the program runs for a long time or uses a lot of memory, freeing the blocks that are no longer needed helps reduce the memory footprint.  Not freeing them may cause the system to run out of memory or start swapping and make the system unstable.
- freeing all allocated blocks upon exit is a good way to check that the program accounts for all allocated blocks, which can be verifies with special tools such as valgrind.

Answer (score -1):

Stack memory gets reclaimed by the Operating System after a program is completed (similar to variables declared within a function when the function ends).

Modern systems free up heap memory after programs finish running but not always and when done, you can't guarantee all of it to be free'd. Thus, you can run into issues such as memory leaks and buffer overflows.

So yes, you can get away with lingering heap data, but it is an inherent risk. If you have complex data structures and it will take an extra O(n) of runtime to free all the nodes, you may not want to do that, it could bog down the runtime and bloat your code body.

Personally, I run valgrind after my programs to make sure the heap is free()'d just to be safe. I apologize for my rambling